# Provide a link to download without creating a file on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, zip, dotnetzip

I want to create a file and give it to download without putting itself on the server.

```
public ActionResult DownloadZip(Guid id){
    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.Password = "123456!";
        // GenareteString();
        // add string to file
        // save zip

        //return zip to user
    }
    return View();
}
```

how to do it

I use DotNetZip

Comment: I've tried both this file to create a virtual, but it did not have nothing, all the functions required to maintain the server.

Comment: It depends if your "ZipFile" can be created in memory. Your link would point to a [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) which will respond with the created file.

Comment: zip.Save(outputStream); - but I do not know how to create this outputStream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use `return View()` but something like:

```
return File(myMemoryStream,                           // zipped data
    System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip,   // "application/zip"
    "default.zip");                                   // suggested download name
```

There are a few overloads available.

The `Controller.File()` and `Controller.View()` helper functions both return types derived from `ActionResult`.

Comment: Anyway you want. I thought you had the creation of the ZIP solved. You can use a (Memory)Stream or a `byte[]` buffer.

Comment: Thanks for MemoryStream outputStream

Answer (score -3):

You need a server to serve people. You can't just write a function and send it to someone over the internet without any "server" mechanism.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to server a file without storing it: Simply serve a stream created in memory (using a HTTP Handler).

Comment: Of course you can. All it takes is the right content-type header in the response.